# Setting up text view text in java file onLoadResource Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to set text in java file.

this is my xml code

**.xml file**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

this is my java code

**java file**

```
 public class account extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView textview;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
            textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

    textview.setText("Register");
                }
               });
   }}
```

issue is if i set title in oncreate it's work fine but if set in onLoadResource then it's not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Also, are you sure the code to set the text is called? You can set a breakpoint and see if it reaches the "setText" call.

Comment: where is you `WebView` placed? your current code shouldn't build as there no `webView` declared anywhere... (not in method, not in class, not in XML snippet)

Comment: I think you are not loading anything in the webview, and `onLoadResource` will only be called when any resource is loaded by `webViewClient`. Use `webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");` to load any url.